# Сменa OOO на ИП в App Store connect

Tags: ios, apple

Купили приложение, бывшие владельцы зарегистрировали как ООО. Мне же нужно ИП (хочу сначала проверить гипотезу и сделать это с минимальным количеством заморочек).
Можно ли сменить ООО на ИП?

Answer (score 0):

Изменить тип аккаунта нельзя. Вы можете создать новый аккаунт и переместить приложение на новый аккаунт. Все пройдет безболезненно. Пользователи ничего не заметят.